# Получение ссылки Google Таблицы

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Использую следующий скрипт для получения URL ссылки из ячейки:

```
function GetURL(input) {
  let myFormula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  let myAddress = myFormula.replace('=GetURL(','').replace(')','');
  let myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(myAddress);
  return myRange.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()
 }
```

[image: Example]

Скрипт отрабатывает только когда имя ссылки не числовое.
Подскажите, как исправить.

[Ссылка на файл](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qg-NILC3RbvqedikS0w33gmNj9_iCKYhiiwc7HiIDM8/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Документацию не читай, вопрос задавай. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalue `RichTextValue — The Rich Text value of the top left cell in the range, or null if the cell value is not text.`

Comment: гугл про проблему знает и исправлять не собирается (`Status
Won't Fix (Intended behavior)`) https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158393310?pli=1

Comment: В коментах пишут, что делать - изменить формат ячейки с `Automatic` на `Plain text`. Тогда начинает работать твой скрипт